# Testing command line parameters

Tags: c#

What is the best way to test a command line parameter from within the Visual Studio C# Express 2010 IDE?  All i see is the "Play" button to start debugging (and running) my program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set command line arguments in the properties of the project:

[image]

Comment: older post, but you saved me a ton of time with this one!

Answer (score 3):

Setting the arguement value in the project properties is good if the values don't change.

If you are wanting to test many different command line arguement combinations, going to the Properties window between each run can get very tedious.  One way to get around this is to place a breakpoint on the `{` at the start of the `Main` method and set a debug watch on the command arguments.

Then all that is needed is to run the program, wait for it to break and then edit the value of the arguement in the watch window.  When you continue execution it will be as if you had given those command line arguements.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project in Solution Explorer, select Properties, then the Debug tab. Here you will see a textbox labeled "Command line arguments". If you enter any arguments here, they will be passed as command line arguments when you debug, ie. "hit Play".